# jar conflict in two applications - maven-shade-plugin relocation

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I need help with maven-shade-plugin.
I have an application A which is planning to add the client of application B. The problem is that, both application A and application B use a library(let's call this conflict-lib) but of different versions. I cannot change the version in any of these application because they are dependent on different versions of Jersey. 
I was told maven-shade-plugin should be able to take care of this issue. 
I looked up a few examples and read the documentation but I don't have a full understanding of how this will work.

I have added the below snippet in my pom.xml of application "B". 
I am going to add the application B dependency in application A. Do I need to add transformers? Is there anything that needs to be added / excluded? Thanks in advance.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.conflict.lib</pattern>
               <shadedPattern>shaded.com.conflict.lib</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

How will this work now ? when i run mvn install, I see below in the console

```
Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing /Users/.../application-b-client/target/application-b-client-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar with /Users/.../application-b-client/target/application-b-client-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-**shaded**.jar
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: /Users/.../application-b-client/dependency-reduced-pom.xml
```

This shaded artifact is not in my .m2 folder. It is just in my projects target folder.  What should I put in the pom.xml of my Application "A" ? 
Currently I simply have:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my</groupId>
        <artifactId>application-b-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Should I replace this with 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.shaded version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks correct to me at first sight.

The shaded .jar *replaces* the original .jar - so don't expect to find both in your repository.

If everything went as expected, there should be a package called 'shaded' inside the `application-b-client-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar` file that holds the relocated package. Is that not the case?

**Edit:**

> this client jar is being used in other projects too, but
>   non-shaded version

If you (or a client) will later need both the original and the shaded `.jar`s, you can add the following configuration:

```
<shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
<shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
```

Instead of replacing the original, this will make it so the shaded `.jar` gets attached *in addition* to the original.

You can then require the artifacts using either:

```
<!-- This is the original non-shaded artifact -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>application-b-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

-or-

```
<!-- This is the shaded artifact -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>application-b-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>shaded</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: My target folder now has original-application-b-client-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar and application-b-client-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar. Does it mean the one without the "original" is the shaded version ? How can I verify this? Does it create a shaded folder in the  package structure? I don't see anything like that. Can I create the shaded jar with a name that included string "shaded" ?

Comment: Exactly - the one without "original" is the shaded version. In order to verify it you can unzip the `.jar` - there should be a 'shaded' folder inside. If there's not, then there's something wrong with the configuration.

Comment: You can change the name of the shaded artifact using the `finalName` configuration property, e.g. `<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-shaded<finalName>`. I would, however, argue against that and use the default names.

Comment: I see, because this client jar is being used in other projects too, but non-shaded version. I will unzip and check if there is a shaded folder inside.

Comment: I checked the jar, it does not have the shaded folder :(

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of shadedClassifierName? Is this better than modifying the finalName ?

Comment: It works, I was using the wrong package name in the relocation elements. Fixed it and it worked.

Comment: I've now updated the answer with a response to a comment.