# Java/Maven how to use a dependency that uses an older version of another dependency that is already used in the project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, dependency-management

In my project we use the version 2.9.0 of jackson-databind.
I want to use a maven dependency (https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-java-client), but it **needs** to use an older version of jackson-databind, because in more recents version they remove a method that the dependency calls (the exception "NoSuchMethod" is raised).

What to do in this case ? Obviously I cannot downgrade the jackson-databind version we use in the project for other things just to please this sole dependency.

Is there a way to keep using the recent version in my project, but make the dependency that needs the older version use the older version ? In my opinion that would be the perfect solution, but I get the feeling it doesn't work that way.

Comment: How old is the version? What method specifically?

Comment: Would creating a fixed version of the troublesome artifact be an option?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I don't know what specific version I just know that it's this method : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/c9e13bc4150e05566953ca570a67e8a84f652a0b/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/BeanUtil.java#L95, but the code in the library I'm using is trying to call this method except with just one parameter (it has two now), that version of the method doesn't exist anymore (thus NoSuchMethod is thrown).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'd like to avoid doing something like that, I would need to have that jar lying in the codebase, not very clean imo, the tech leaders will frown at me

Comment: @genku if the troublesome jar does not have a newer version and you don’t want to fix it properly then I see no other reliable option than splitting your code into separate applications.

Comment: Consider asking your tech leaders what to do in this situation. A decision will need to be made.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen what needs to be done to fix it properly ? You mean making a P.R. into the github of the library and have them make a new release ?

Comment: Ask your tech how lead they want things done.  You might have to fix in an inhouse fork.

Comment: I looked up the maven-shade thing, it might do the trick, this post explains it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326031/jar-conflict-in-two-applications-maven-shade-plugin-relocation . Though I don't understand how it works very well yet

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Maven Shade Plugin : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html

It allows you to rename the package of a version

Comment: I'm not sure how I would use that for my problem, could you explain how ?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you find a solution to have two versions of the same dependency included in your project. You still have the problem, that when running the application in one JVM the classloader will not know which version of class is necessary now so it will load and provide the first class thats found in the class-loader-hierarchy. So you can not use two Versions of one Class in the same ClassLoader.